# Spring Boot is picking profile name correct but selecting property values from default profile

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application with below application.yml:

```
spring:
  profiles: qa
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@qfxo001z.unix:1523/AXLET02Q"
    username: "axle"
    #password will be loaded from secured external file location
    driver-class-name: "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
---
banner:
  location: "config/banner.txt"
logging:
  config: "classpath:config/log4j2-spring.xml"
spring:
  profiles:
    default: dev
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE"
    username: "axle"
    #password will be loaded from secured external file location
    driver-class-name: "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
db:
  password:
    propertyFilePath: "/tmp/db-password.properties"
instances: &instances
  - DAPI_0
  - DAPI_1
  - DAPI_2
  - DAPI_R1
  - CNX
chronicle:
  inputQueuePath: /tmp/${INSTANCE}/queue-v1/input
  outputQueuePath: /tmp/${INSTANCE}/queue-v1/output
```

When I am trying to run the executable jar through command, it picks the correct profile name but select the property values from default profile:

```
java -jar client-stp-grid-publisher-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.profile.active=qa
```

Can anyone please help me to understand where I am going wrong?

Comment: Just asking, `--spring.profile.active=qa` works fine? I thought it should be `-Dspring.profiles.active=qa` (profile vs profiles).

Comment: All profiles extend the default profile, you should override the value of each propertie in a specific profile if you do not need its default value.

Comment: @staszko032...sorry typo mistake it was profiles

Comment: @akuma8...correct..so ideally when spring.profiles.active=qa passed then it should pick datasource:
    url: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@qfxo001z.unix:1523/AXLET02Q" but spring boot is picking the default value.